# Spring thymeleaf th:each fails with Field or property "" cannot be found on null

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf, but I have a few other pages working.  However, this is the first time I am using th:each and I am getting an error.  At runtime, I get "Field or property 'licenseName' cannot be found on null".  I ran debug and I am passing an ArrayList of objects in my ModelAnView object.  I have copied and pasted over the model key to the th:each attribute, just in case I mist typed something.  Here is the offending code:

```
                    <select th:remove="all-but-first" id="accountPlans">
                        <option th:each="license : ${availableLicenses}" th:text="${licnese.licenseName}" value="None">-- Select a Plan --</option>
                        <option value="Free">Free - A plan to learn the basics</option>
                        <option value="Intro">Intro - Starter plan for a small founding group</option>
                        <option value="Basic">Basic - A plan for a small group</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `licnese.licenseName` instead of **`license.licenseName`**. That, probably, is  the reason for your error